# Does Rails3.2.1 can not refresh haml view  in development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am using Rails3.2.1 and haml engine, I found that the page can not be update when I modified the haml view code. I am sure I am in development environment.

Comment: Do it uses proper .haml template after rails server restart?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen before because I had `.erb` files next to my `.haml` files.

Make sure you don't have any `.erb` files as they seem to take precedence over `.haml` files. For example if your files are like so...

```
app/views/pages/home.html.erb
app/views/pages/home.html.haml
```

you wont see any changes to `home.html.haml`

Comment: Right, but I delete the erb, it still happens :(

Comment: do you have `gem 'haml'` and `gem 'haml-rails'` in your Gemfile?